# How to create custom back button in navigationBar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = .init(image: "back_icon".image, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
}
```

For this above code, I got my back_icon image with the default back image

[image: Output Image]

Any idea to remove the default back button at the same time preserving swipe edge to pop viewController.

Comment: let appearence = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearence.setBackIndicatorImage("back_icon".image!, transitionMaskImage: "back_icon".image!)
navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearence


This changes the back button indicator image & works as expected..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change the back button image **globally** by using

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
```

And if you only want to change it in some places:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "arrow-back")
```

Removing an arrow at all would be as simple as

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove default back Button by following way:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

And manually add navigation items in left side using `navigationitem.leftBarButtonItem.`

Hope it helps!

Comment: It just removes the back button text but not default back icon
I found the solution check in the question comments

But thanks for spending you valuable time for my question. 